# Read XHTML And Custom Tags Into DOM Tree

Tags: java, xml, dom, flying-saucer

I am doing conversion from XHTML to PDF using flying saucer, it works perfectly but now i want to add bookmarks, and according to the fs documentation it should be done like this:

```
<bookmarks>
    <bookmark name='1. Foo bar baz' href='#1'>
      <bookmark name='1.1 Baz quux' href='#1.2'>
      </bookmark>
    </bookmark>
    <bookmark name='2. Foo bar baz' href='#2'>
      <bookmark name='2.1 Baz quux' href='#2.2'>
      </bookmark>
    </bookmark>
</bookmarks>
```

That should be put into the HEAD section, I have done that but the SAXParser wont read the file anymore, saying:

```
line 11 column 14 - Error: <bookmarks> is not recognized!
line 11 column 25 - Error: <bookmark> is not recognized!
```

I have a local entity resolver set up and have even added the bookmarks to a DTD,

```
<!--flying saucer bookmarks -->
<!ELEMENT bookmarks (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST bookmarks %attrs;>

<!ELEMENT bookmark (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST bookmark %attrs;>
```

But it just wont parse, I am out of ideas, please help.

**EDIT**

I am using the following code to parse:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
builder.setEntityResolver(new LocalEntityResolver());
document = builder.parse(is);
```

**EDIT**

Here is LocalEntityResolver:

```
 class LocalEntityResolver implements EntityResolver {

    private static final Logger LOG = ESAPI.getLogger(LocalEntityResolver.class);
    private static final Map<String, String> DTDS;
    static {
        DTDS = new HashMap<String, String>();
        DTDS.put("-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd");
        DTDS.put("-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd");
        DTDS.put("-//W3C//ENTITIES Latin 1 for XHTML//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-lat1.ent");
        DTDS.put("-//W3C//ENTITIES Symbols for XHTML//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-symbol.ent");
        DTDS.put("-//W3C//ENTITIES Special for XHTML//EN",
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml-special.ent");
    }

    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
            throws SAXException, IOException {
        InputSource input_source = null;
        if (publicId != null && DTDS.containsKey(publicId)) {
            LOG.debug(Logger.EVENT_SUCCESS, "Looking for local copy of [" + publicId + "]");

            final String dtd_system_id = DTDS.get(publicId);
            final String file_name = dtd_system_id.substring(
                    dtd_system_id.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, dtd_system_id.length());

            InputStream input_stream = FileUtil.readStreamFromClasspath(
                    file_name, "my/class/path",
                    getClass().getClassLoader());
            if (input_stream != null) {
                LOG.debug(Logger.EVENT_SUCCESS, "Found local file [" + file_name + "]!");
                input_source = new InputSource(input_stream);
            }
        }

        return input_source;
    }
}
```

My document builder factory implementation is :
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

Comment: I think you need to provide more details. How can I or anyone else reproduce the problem?

Comment: Basically i want to parse valid XHTML with certain unknown elements into a DOM tree using the W3C Transitional DTD. If you want to reproduce take any valid XHTML, add the bookmark html and try to parse into a dom tree

Comment: What is that `LocalEntityResolver`? Where does it come from? I cannot find any message in the Xerces source  that fits  `{element} is not recognized!`.

Comment: Can you give us a small, complete example input document that shows up the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, I finally found the problem. Sorry for making you guys debug the code, the problem was that in my code there was a call to JTidy.parse just before the DOM parsing occurred, this resulted in the content to be parsed to be empty and i did not even catch that, the actual Error was, `Premature End of file` from SAX.

Thanks to Matt Gibson, while i was going through the code to compile a short input document, i found the bug.

My code now includes a check to see if the content was null

```
/**
 * parses String content into a valid XML document.
 * @param content the content to be parsed.
 * @return the parsed document or <tt>null</tt>
 */
private static Document parse(final String content) {
    Document document = null;
    try {
        if (StringUtil.isNull(content)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot parse null "
                    + "content into a DOM object!");
        }

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content
                .getBytes(CONTEXT.getEncoding()));

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        builder.setEntityResolver(new LocalEntityResolver());
        document = builder.parse(is);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, "parsing failed "
                + "for content[" + content + "]", ex);
    }

    return document;
}
```

Comment: Yet another reason to reference [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ;-) I was indeed trying to reproduce your issue and was having a hard time (what library does FileUtil come from for example ..)

Comment: No worries. Glad you found it!